# How to execute NUnit test cases from command prompt

Tags: c#, automation, nunit

How can I execute a test case from Command Console using NUnit? I had set of Selenium Tests written in C# based on NUnit framework. I need to execute the test cases simply by running from command console.

In JUnit we can run test case from cmd as

```
java junit.swingui.TestRunner test.Run
```

How can we do above in NUnit?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`nunit-console.exe`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.2.10) to run tests from the command line.

For example:

```
nunit-console.exe /xml:results.xml path/to/test/assembly.dll
```

This will run the unit tests and save the results in the results.xml file, which you can work with easily.

See the [documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.10) for all of the various command line switches that are available.

Comment: I had sharp developer. How can we create dll from it

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Have you just started using SharpDevelop? In that case, a unit test assembly is created as a normal _C# Class Library_ project, and the reference to _NUnit.Framework_ is easily added by clicking on the Reference icon in the _Unit tests_ view. As far as I know, there is no command prompt option in #develop, but you can easily run the unit test from the Unit tests view.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I am able to execute from sharp develop but I need the required from command prompt

Comment: Link do current documentation: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html

Answer (score 24):

I would like to add a few words about the latest version of NUnit. **The name of the console application has changed** to `nunit3-console.exe` in NUnit 3. Information about all possible options can be found in the official [documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line). For example, run all tests in the assembly (the results are saved into the `TestResult.xml` file by default).

```
nunit3-console.exe path/to/test/assembly.dll
```

Answer (score 9):

I've just find another nice solution:

Adding the following command to the "Build Events" / "Post-Build Events", will run the tests in Nunit-Gui automatically after the project has been built.

I hope this can be useful:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-x86.exe" $(TargetPath) /run
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio: 2017, 2019(Preview)
On Mac use below command:

```
nunit-console <path/to/project>/<project-name>/bin/Debug/<project-solution-name>.dll
```

For example:

> nunit-console /Users/pratik/Projects/selenium-mac13/selenium-test/bin/Debug/selenium-test.dll

Answer (score 0):

nunit3-console.exe "path of the testfile (dll)"

Answer (score 0):

- Working on a Windows 10 Desktop with Visual Studio
- I had a set of tests in C# where I'd set the test method with Category==API.
- To run the tests (Nunit3-console) remotely via Bamboo, I added this Bamboo Powershell script:

  ```
  Invoke-Command -Credential $credentials -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock{
       $pathToDdrive = "D:"
       $pathtoDLL = Join-Path $pathToDdrive -ChildPath "RestOfThePathToDLL"

       cd D:\...\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools
       .\nunit3-console.exe $pathToDLL --where "cat=='API'" 
  }
  ```