# Is there any way to run Nunit test using test adapter in command prompt?

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, nunit, azure-devops

I want to use it in ***VSTS CI pipeline using a CMD task***.I saw it can be done using nunit3-console.exe but it needs to be installed in build server and I don't want to VSTest task.

Comment: Can you talk us through why https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085857/34092 won't suit your needs? Does https://github.com/nunit/docs/issues/64 help?

Comment: include more details on your question

Comment: It said to use NUnint console which I need to install in build server and I don't want it.I heard that NUnit adapter can be used to run test in command prompt.But did not got any help till now.

Comment: not permitted. :(

Comment: Who said it was not permitted? Why did they say it was not permitted?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: it is solved..need to download nunit console from nuget package manager and you will see in the package folder there is nuget exe file which needs to point in vsts pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio Test task calls vstest.console.exe tool to run test, you can check the command in detail log.

First, install **NUnit** and **NUnit3TestAdapter** nuget packages to your test project.

Secondly:

For .net framework project, just call command like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" {test assembly (dll) path} /logger:trx /TestAdapterPath:{package folder path}`

For .net core project:

1. Specify package path in **Destination directory** input box of NuGet restore task
2. Command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" {test assembly (dll) path} /logger:trx "/TestAdapterPath:\"{package path (step 1)} \"" /framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0`